# Regex for removing a specific BBCode from a string

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to write a simple method for removing specific BBCodes from an input string.

For example, where I have an input of:

```
string input = "[b]Hello World![/b]";
```

I would want to be able to do:

```
Remove(input, "b");
```

And get an output of:

```
"Hello World!"
```

Regex really isn't my strong suit. I've managed to piece together the following from google:

```
public static string Remove(string input, string code)
{
    string pattern = string.Format(@"\[{0}\].*?\[\/{1}\]", code, code);

    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Unfortunately this returns an empty string for my given example.

Can anyone advise me on how I can correct my regex to get the desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple regex: `\[/?{0}\]`

**Your regex is removing the whole string**

- Your regex `\[{0}\].*?\[\/{1}\]` is removing the entire `[b]...[/b]` string. That's why you are getting an empty string from the replacement.
- What you need is to remove only the `[b]` and `[b]`. In normal regex, this is expressed quite simply with `\[/?b\]`, where the slash is made optional by the `?`
- In your parametrized regex, something like `\[/?{0}\]` will work.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would capture the string `Hello World!` inside the second group.

```
^(.*?)((?<=])[^[]*)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bB2xO6)

So replace all your input string with the second captured group.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that both starting and trailing special symbol must occur and you don't want them to be in a result, you can use positive look back ((?<=(your symbols here))) and positive  look ahead ((?=(your symbols here))) for specified characters.

Complete answer will look like this:

```
(?<=(\[{0}\])).*(?=(\[\/{1}\]))
```

Comment: please provide explanation to your answer so that OP and Other user can learn

Comment: Thank you for comment. Is it more approproiate now?

Comment: Yes! looks better than before :)